# How does surface tension work?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

If surface tension acts tangential to the surface, then how does a water drop shrink or compress inward?

Answer (score 1):

Surface tension is the tendency of liquid surfaces to shrink into the minimum surface area possible.

At liquid-air interfaces, surface tension results from the greater attraction of liquid molecules to each other (due to [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(chemistry))) than to the molecules in the air (due to [adhesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhesion)).

There are two primary mechanisms in play. One is an inward force on the surface molecules causing the liquid to contract. The second is a tangential force parallel to the surface of the liquid. The net effect is the liquid behaves as if its surface were covered with a stretched elastic membrane.

---

Another way to view surface tension is in terms of energy. A molecule in contact with a neighbor is in a lower state of energy than if it were alone. The interior molecules have as many neighbors as they can possibly have, but the boundary molecules are missing neighbors (compared to interior molecules) and therefore have higher energy. For the liquid to minimize its energy state, the number of higher energy boundary molecules must be minimized. The minimized number of boundary molecules results in a minimal surface area. As a result of surface area minimization, a surface will assume the smoothest shape it can (mathematical proof that "smooth" shapes minimize surface area relies on the use of the Euler–Lagrange equation). Since any curvature in the surface shape results in a greater area, a higher energy will also result.

---

~ References

- [Surface Tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension)
- [Euler-Lagrange's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)

Answer (score 1):

Think of surface tension like a balloon membrane stretched over the surface. What you have asked is the same as asking why a balloon takes the curved shape of a sphere. A curved membrane under tension enables a pressure difference to exist across the membrane (by a force balance).  This is described by the Young-Laplace equation.

The main difference between a real balloon membrane and surface tension "membrane effect" is that the surface tension does not change when the surface is stretched while and the tension in a real balloon-type membrane increases.

Answer (score 0):

Surface tension $\sigma$ is a gradient in force $\sigma = dF/dr$. It maps differences in local forces from one region to another *in the surface plane*. When $\sigma$ is viewed this way, it is essentially internal to the system of interest. Using this view, we cannot generally appreciate why bulk materials form different shapes (i.e. spheres versus infinitely flat plates). The best we can do in some sense is use this view to predict for example what might happen when we deposit a solution of soap on a flat surface of water. The net force on the soap solution (due to the differences in surface tension between the water and the soap solution) drives the soap solution to example as a film.

For a pure material, interfacial tension $\sigma$ is also a gradient in Gibb's energy *as you cross the area between two interfaces* at constant temperature and pressure $\sigma = dG/dA$. A statement of the spontaneity criteria in the second law is that systems will seek to minimize their Gibb's energy to reach equilibrium. We can appreciate from this view why bulk systems of a given (finite) amount of material will form spheres at equilibrium. A sphere has has the lowest physical surface area for any finite physical system.

How might a transition from a hypothetical physical system having an infinite planar surface area occur to form a sphere? How can $\sigma$ as a tangential force gradient make things form into spheres rather than keeping them as flat surfaces? This question is beyond the scope of reasoning. A tangential force gradient is not causing the change in shape, the Gibb's energy gradient is driving the system to its equilibrium shape as it forms. Simply put, no physical system every starts with an infinite planar surface area and then transitions to a sphere. All physical processes that nucleate a new phase in an otherwise unconstrained spatial region always nucleate the new phase to its equilibrium state, which is spherical in shape as driven by the need to minimize surface area.

Certain consequences follow from a spherically shaped control volume of pure material having a surface tension. One of them is the Young-Laplace equation for the difference in pressure inside and outside the sphere. In this case, we see another unique application of surface tension as a tangential in-plane force gradient giving rise to or being linked to an interfacial across-plane pressure gradient.